# Prolog bigger from list element pairs to new list

Tags: list, prolog

I want to find the bigger value from a list's element's pairs.
Ie. list=[5,7,4,5,6,8] the pairs are [5,7], [7,4], [4,5] etc.
Right now I have this little code snippet:

```
bigger([],X).
bigger([E1],[H|E1]).
bigger([E1,E2|T],[H|_]):-
   (E1>E2,bigger([E2|T],[H|E1]));
   (E1<E2,bigger([E2|T],[H|E2])).
```

The solution should look like:

```
?- bigger([5,7,4,5,6,8],X).
X = [7,7,5,6,8,8]
```

EDIT:
Deleted the remove/3 lines, since they're wrong.

I'll give MY understanding of how the code works.

1. Empty given list check.
2. One element list check, adds it to output list end ([H|E1])
3. More than one element in given list, output list

   3.1 First two element check (E1 >/< E2)

   3.2 New recursive query without E1 (first element)

   3.3 Whichever is bigger is output list's last element now.

Comment: So for every pair you want to return the biggest one?

Comment: Can you actually explain why you think your code snippet should work? RIght now it does not look to go in the direction of a solution. Convince yourself that it works, such that you spot the errors.

Comment: Yes, that's the main goal: get the bigger element and add it to the output list (last element always goes to output).

Comment: Especially the second clause is troublesome, since `E1` is an element in the first argument, and you use it as a tail in your second argument.

Comment: Another aspect: the answer contains as much elements as the "input". Shouldn't the length of `X` be one less than the given list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll show you my solution of your problem (and the result shouldn't be `X = [7,7,5,6,8]`? I'll make this version.)

```
gtr(X,Y,Y) :-
        Y>=X.
gtr(X,_,X).

bigger([],[]).
bigger([_], []).
bigger([X,Y|R], [Z|H]) :-
        bigger([Y|R],H), gtr(X,Y,Z),!.
```

If you want to have last element appear in this list anyway than just change second `bigger` function.

Answer (score 2):

Since the relation is describing lists you could opt to use DCGs for the task:

```
max_of(X,X,Y) :- X >= Y.   % X is maximum if X>=Y
max_of(Y,X,Y) :- Y > X.    % Y is maximum if Y>X

list_biggers(L,B) :-
   phrase(biggers(L),B).   % the DCG biggers//1 describes B based on L

biggers([]) -->            % if the list is empty
   [].                     % there's no element in the biggers list
biggers([X]) -->           % if the list contains just one element
   [X].                    % it is in the biggers list
biggers([X,Y|Xs]) -->      % if the list contains at least two elements
   {max_of(M,X,Y)},        % the maximum of them
   [M],                    % is in the biggers list
   biggers([Y|Xs]).        % the same holds for [Y|Xs]
```

This definition is sticking to your reading of the task, that is, in the case of a one-element list the only element is in the list of bigger elements:

```
?- list_biggers([5,7,4,5,6,8],B).
B = [7, 7, 5, 6, 8, 8] ;
false.

?- list_biggers([1],B).
B = [1] ;
false.
```

If you prefer the reading suggested by @Armatorix, just change the second DCG-rule to

```
biggers([_X]) -->
   [].
```

This way the queries above yields the following results:

```
?- list_biggers([5,7,4,5,6,8],B).
B = [7, 7, 5, 6, 8] ;
false.

?- list_biggers([1],B).
B = [] ;
false.
```

Note that the list has to be sufficiently instantiated. Otherwise you get an error:

```
?- list_biggers([X,Y,Z],B).
ERROR: >=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

If the list only contains integers, you can remedy this problem by using CLP(FD). Add a line to include the library and change max_of/2 like so:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

max_of(X,X,Y) :- X #>= Y.
max_of(Y,X,Y) :- Y #> X.
```

Now the query above delivers all 4 expected solutions:

```
?- list_biggers([X,Y,Z],B).
B = [X, Y, Z],
X#>=Y,
Y#>=Z ;
B = [X, Z, Z],
X#>=Y,
Y#=<Z+ -1 ;
B = [Y, Y, Z],
X#=<Y+ -1,
Y#>=Z ;
B = [Y, Z, Z],
X#=<Y+ -1,
Y#=<Z+ -1 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to construct logical programs, one needs to *think logical*. Based on the problem statement, there are three possibilities here:

- we have an empty list, in that case the result is an empty list as well:

  ```
  bigger([],[]).
  ```
- in case we have a list with one element, the problem is underspecified. I would say that the result should be an empty list, but your example seems to suggest that we return that number, since we then have a 1-tuple, and the maximum of a 1-tuple is of course the single element in the tuple:

  ```
  bigger([H],[H]).
  ```
- in case the list contains two or more elements `[H1,H2|T]`, then `H1` and `H2` are the first two elements. In that case we construct a vitual tuple in our head `[H1,H2]` and calculate the maximum, which is thus `M is max(H1,H2)`. We prepend `M` to the resulting list of the recursion. That recursion is done on the list `[H2|T]`: the list where we popped `H1` from:

  ```
  bigger([H1,H2|T],[M|U]) :-
      M is max(H1,H2),
      bigger([H2|T],U).
  ```

Or putting this all together:

```
bigger([],[]).
bigger([H],[H]).
bigger([H1,H2|T],[M|U]) :-
    M is max(H1,H2),
    bigger(T,U).
```